# How to stop python websocket connection after some seconds?

Tags: python, websocket

I am trying to develop a short script that connects to a real-time stock data provider through a websocket API, gets some data, makes some calculations, stores the results in a database and stops.

EDIT: I need to keep the connection alive for a few seconds until I get all required data. Thus, breaking the connection after the first message is not an option.

The problem I am facing is how to stop the `run_forever()` connection.

This is what I have so far:

```
import websocket
import json

def on_open(ws):
    channel_data = {
        "action": "subscribe",
        "symbols": "ETH-USD,BTC-USD"
    }
    ws.send(json.dumps(channel_data))
    
def on_message(ws, message):
    # Do some stuff (store messages for a few seconds)
    print(message)
    
def on_close(ws):
    print("Close connection")
    
socket = "wss://ws.url"
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
ws.close()

# Once the connection is closed, continue with the program
```

I do not want to stay connected after the "Do some stuff" is executed, how can I force the connection close?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: "*how can I force the connection close?*" ... by calling `ws.close()` when "*the "Do some stuff" is executed*", perhaps? Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I was not too clear. The API provides several messages (actually, stock prices) but I need to keep the connection alive until all requested stocks are provided. Thus, I can´t close the connection in the first message received. Is there any way to set a counter? or a timer?

Comment: Instantiate a global variable that keeps track of the messages you've received and bump it up each time against the `symbols` you requested. Once the lists match, invoke `close()`.

Comment: I have tried something similar. I declared `global n` `n=0` at the beginning of `on_open()` function and `n+=1` inside the `on_message()` function. But if I try to `print(n)` inside this function, it does not seem to do anything

Answer (score 6):

I managed how to solve this. I leave my solution in case it is useful to someone.

I just added some attributes to the `ws` object that allows me to track the number of messages received and store them into a list to work with once the connection is closed.

```
import websocket
import json

def on_open(ws):
    channel_data = {
        "action": "subscribe",
        "symbols": "ETH-USD,BTC-USD"
    }
    ws.send(json.dumps(channel_data))
    
def on_message(ws, message):
    
    ws.messages_count+=1
    ws.messages_storage.append(message)
    
    if ws.messages_count>50:
        ws.close()
    
def on_close(ws):
    print("Close connection")
    
socket = "wss://ws.url"
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message)

# Create a counter and an empty list to store messages
ws.messages_count = 0
ws.messages_storage = []

# Run connection
ws.run_forever()

# Close connection
ws.close()

# Continue with the program
```